# Need help simplifying a Radical Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> I need help for simplifying of the following rational expression. 
>   $$x\sqrt{2x}+2\sqrt{2x^3}+\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{2x}}.$$

No matter how hard I try to manipulate it I keep getting the wrong answer. According to the answer key the solution should be $4x\sqrt{2x}$.

Comment: If you put in $x=1$, what do you get? By the way, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $4 \sqrt{2} x^{3/2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\sqrt{2x}+2\sqrt{2x^3}+\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{2x}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x}x\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{2x}2\sqrt{2x^3}+2x^2}{\sqrt{2x}}$$
$$\frac{2x^2+4x^2+2x^2}{\sqrt{2x}}$$
$$\frac{8x^2}{\sqrt{2x}}$$
$$\frac{8x^2}{\sqrt{2x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2x}}{\sqrt{2x}} = \frac{8x^2\sqrt{2x}}{2x}=4x\sqrt{2x}$$

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's just $$\sqrt{2x^3}+2\sqrt{2x^3}+\sqrt{2x^3}=4\sqrt{2x^3}=4x\sqrt{2x}$$
Because $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{x}}=\sqrt{x^3}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt2}=\frac{(\sqrt2)^2}{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2$.